# Redefine \title for possibility of a forced line breaking in a predefined place

Tags: titles

When we use the macro `\title{Some Title}`, the macro just assign the `Some Text` to another internal one `\@title` as defined in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
```

We can use the `\@title` in various places of document, for example, in `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}` for pdf-meta, or in some another places of an document. For example, if title looks like

`\title{The World Big Idea: with small corrections}`.

The some places need to be shown as `The World Big Idea:` line break here `with small corrections`. But in some another places it  should stand still in a single line.

**How to redefine `\title` or possible, any other good ideas?**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Some Title}

    \begin{document}

    \makeatletter
        \@title % One can use \@title in different places
    \makeatother

    \makeatletter 
        %\@title Here one need to use the same text, but with line breack between "Same" and "Tile"
        Some\\Title
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this depends on what uses for `\@title` you have in mind.

Comment: @moewe I use the `\@title` in `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}`. Here it shoul be in single line, but in titlepage I need to breack the line in some place.

Comment: @sergiokapone Off-topic`\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}` is unnecessary, the title is used per default for the pdf meta data

Comment: @samcarter Ok, but `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}` was just for example.

Comment: Mhhh, `\@title` is one macro and it can obviously only have one definition at a time. You could write something like `\title{Some \mypossiblenewline Title}` and redefine the meaning of `\mypossiblenewline` from context to context. But I think it would be tricky to have *one* place of definition for `\@title` and several possible outcomes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a naive idea.

Use a placeholder in the definition of `\@title` via `\title` and redefine that placeholder variable as required by the context.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand*{\mypossiblenewline}{\newline}
\title{Some \mypossiblenewline Title}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \@title
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\mypossiblenewline}{}
  \@title
  \endgroup
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

You could wrap that up in one command, for example

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sergiotitlenobreak}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\mypossiblenewline}{}%
  \@title
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sergiotitlewithbreak}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\mypossiblenewline}{\newline}%
  \@title
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

but that would not be expandable (which could be a problem depending on the context).

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is some solution of my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Save two more variables, for lack of creativity I named them `\realtitle` and `\inlinetitle`. In the second one, `\\` tokens are substituted with spaces,  first removing spaces at either side of `\\`. Thus it is immaterial if you input any of

```
\title{Some Title \\ with line breaks}
\title{Some Title\\ with line breaks}
\title{Some Title\\with line breaks}
```

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\title}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:cn { @title } { #1 } % needed by \maketitle
  \tl_gset:Nn { \realtitle } { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \tl_gset:Nx \inlinetitle { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\author{author}
\title{Some Title \\ with line breaks}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle=\inlinetitle
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

The title of this document is ``\inlinetitle''.

\begin{center}
\realtitle
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also cope with `\\[<dimen>]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\title}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:cn { @title } { #1 } % needed by \maketitle
  \tl_gset:Nn { \realtitle } { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \inlinetitle { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s* \c{\\}(\[[^\]]*\])+ \s* } { \  } \inlinetitle
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\author{author}
\title{Some Title \\[1ex] with line breaks \\[1ex] and added spacing}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle=\inlinetitle
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

The title of this document is ``\inlinetitle''.

\begin{center}
\realtitle
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Different approach: instead of redefining `\@title`, you can use `\texorpdfstring` to specify two versions, one without linebreaks which will be used in the pdf meta data and one with linebreak to be displayed in the pdf

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{\texorpdfstring{Some\newline Title}{Some title}}

    \begin{document}

    \makeatletter
        \@title % One can use \@title in different places
    \makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I force line bracking only one place of document, but not in others?

Comment: @sergiokapone can you give an example where you want it without linebreak? You could specify an optional shorttitle

Comment: It is hard to give an example, because in some places of document the `\@title` should be in one line, but in some another it should to break in predefined place. Fo example, if title looks like `\title{The World Big Idea: with small corrections}`. The some places need to be  break `The World Big Idea: \\ with small corrections`

Comment: @sergiokapone If it is hard to give an example, it is also hard to answer your question. In your question you only mentioned that you need one line for the pdf meta data and this is what I covered in my answer

Comment: @sergiokapone Off-topic: Don't use \\ for line breaks

Comment: I think, maybe it is possible to  define `\title` with an optional argument that determines whether to break it or not?